# Remove only one not all items in linkedlist

Tags: java

I am trying to remove one of the item in linkedlist.

```
private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<>();

items.add(new Item("Movie1", "2010", "2"));
items.add(new Item("Movie1", "2010", "2"));
```

I try to check if the item exists in the list.

If the item exists then remove the item.

Just it removing all the item.

I just want to remove one item 
So, the result should be after removing.

```
[Movie1, 2010, 2];
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks.

Comment: `java.util.LinkedList` doesn't have an add method that accepts 3 Strings as an argument. Is LinkedList your own custom implementation? Because with the standard LinkedList the code will not even come close to compiling.

Comment: oh yeah bro item is another class that accept three parameters.

Comment: Then it should be `items.add(new Item("Movie1", "2010", "2"));` As the code is currently posted there isn't a single creation of an `Item` seen anywhere.

Comment: This issue cannot be reproduced for standard implementation of the `LinkedList`.  Please provide code of your `Item` implementation and how exactly you are removing the item to make it a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you're removing items in a loop, then after you remove the first item, break out of the loop (with the break statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use [remove(int index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int))

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Objects;

class Item {
    String name, year, id;

    public Item(String name, String year, String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, year, id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Item other = (Item) obj;
        return this.name.equals(other.name) && this.year.equals(other.year) && this.id.equals(other.id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + ", Year: " + year + ", ID: " + id;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();
        Item item1 = new Item("Movie1", "2010", "2");
        Item item2 = new Item("Movie2", "2020", "3");
        items.add(item1);
        items.add(item1);
        items.add(item2);
        System.out.println("Before: ");
        System.out.println(items);

        remove(items, item1);
        remove(items, item2);

        System.out.println("After: ");
        System.out.println(items);

        // Trying to remove item1 again
        remove(items, item1);
        System.out.println("Result: ");
        System.out.println(items);
    }

    /**
     * If list contains more than one occurrence of item, removes the first
     * occurrence of item from list
     * 
     * @param items from which the first occurrence of item has to be removed
     * @param item
     */
    static void remove(LinkedList<Item> items, Item item) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).equals(item)) {
                if (items.subList(i + 1, items.size()).contains(items.get(i))) {
                    items.remove(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before: 
[Name: Movie1, Year: 2010, ID: 2, Name: Movie1, Year: 2010, ID: 2, Name: Movie2, Year: 2020, ID: 3]
After: 
[Name: Movie1, Year: 2010, ID: 2, Name: Movie2, Year: 2020, ID: 3]
Result: 
[Name: Movie1, Year: 2010, ID: 2, Name: Movie2, Year: 2020, ID: 3]
```

Comment: But it's failing for for if there's only  one item

Comment: @salamander - you mean, if there is only one element, it should retain? If yes, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Let me know if it fulfils your requirement.

Comment: I just found that if there's only one item1 and item2 and try to remove with remove(items,item1) it will automatically remove the item1. I don't know that's happening

Comment: should I posed a new question? also, if there is like item1, item2, item3 it's not working propapbly thanks.

Comment: There was a silly mistake. I've corrected it. Test it again and let me know in case of any further issue/doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the list Collections contains method and then remove it.

```
Item item1 = new Item("Movie1", "2010", "2");
if(items.contains(item1){
  items.remove(item1)
}
```

Also, for the above code to work you need to override hashcode and equals method in Item POJO.